# .NET Outlook AddIn: "The custom form cannot be opened. Outlook will use an Outlook form instead. Out of memory or system resources"

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin

I'm writing a fairly simple Outlook 2013 addin, the aim is to periodically loop through the Appointment items and do something with each one. I'm doing this work within a `BackgroundWorker` so as to not block the main UI.

Pseudo code is this:

```
if (!Monitor.TryEnter(Lockobj)) return;
var bw = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
bw.DoWork += (sender, e) => Worker();
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
bw.RunWorkerAsync();

public void static Worker() {
    var application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    var mapiNamespace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    var calendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    var outlookItems = calendarFolder.Items;
    outlookItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
    outlookItems.Sort("[Start]");
    foreach (var appointmentItem in outlookItems.OfType<AppointmentItem>())
    {
        DoThingWithItem(appointmentItem);
    }
    Monitor.Exit(Lockobj);
}
```

However, when I kick this background worker off, it runs for a bit and then throws an error as a messagebox saying: `The custom form cannot be opened. Outlook will use an Outlook form instead. Out of memory or system resources`.

How do I debug this? What's causing outlook to think that it's run out of memory?

Comment: Are you "opening"/modifying the `appointmentItem` inside `DoThingWithItem`?

Comment: I'm reading things out of it (`ResponseStatus`, `Start`, `End`, `Subject`, `Body` etc) but not modifying it.